Electromagnetic velocity in a filter
I read a paper a while back describing that most group delay variation in RF systems is due to filters in them. (I have a reference if anyone might want that.) We even use filters as deliberate distortion devices in BERT loops.   But I can't find anything describing the electrical length of a typical filter compared to its physical length.
E.g. if you have a waveguide filter operating in the 10 GHz region, whose physical length is 1m, what would its effective path length be, compared to 1m of surrounding rigid waveguide, or coax?
I'm in no position to go back to fundamentals and try to calculate this right now.  It would probably take me days.  I'm really still more familiar with optics than circuits.  If the impedance of the filter is matched to the transmission line around it, technically it seems like the EM wave velocity in the filter would equal its velocity in any surrounding 50 Ohm coax or waveguide.  But I'm not sure.
I'm also not in a position to pull any components out and put a network analyzer on them, which should be able to tell electrical length.  (I've never used one for that before, but it should do it.)

The length is the physical length plus the effect of the velocity of propagation and, if you know the effective parameters of the filter you can work this out.

The DSP stack exchange has various questions about zero delay filters that would probably clarify this for you. See: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/66497/how-does-one-make-a-zero-latency-linear-phase-or-natural-phase-filter

generally the narrow the resonance, the longer the excess delay through the filter

Thanks.   I checked that link but don't see anything there that is helping.  The focus there seemed to be digital.   I still don't have a good answer to this.  Andy, what effective parameters of the filter would one need to work this out?  There is no index of refraction given for filters.    In a linear medium  v = 1/sqrt(mu*epsilon) = c/n.  I know that a filter is not a linear medium, by design, but I am only interested in the velocity in the passband.  And I'm hoping for some rule of thumb; which there really should be for a passband.   I might need to ask this in the physics forum.
